# Can we please have our stars back?

Tags: feature-request, design

One thing I miss in [our new theme](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12073/19561) is our field of stars background image.

Now I've noticed that [the Mathematics Stack](https://math.stackexchange.com) still has its background image, even though it already has the new theme.

**Can we please have our stars back?**

The left-nav is in black, so that would need another colour for it work against such a dark background, of course.

Comment: See the [answer/feature request](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12088/58193) on the dupe.