# Why was the background color changed to white (or near-white) on the Sci-Fi SE page?

Tags: feature-request

Whoa, what happened? We used to have a darker background, much easier on the eyes.

Comment: See [Science Fiction & Fantasy's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12073/31394) Also [Do we want a custom background with the new theme?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12092/31394) and [What should the new background/theme look like?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12110/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah, got it. I missed the discussion on background themes.

Comment: Maybe you would like to [swap places](https://english.stackexchange.com/) with EL&U? I'd give 10,000 of my EL&U rep to have a banner as beautiful as yours.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Powers That Be are trying to make it easier to manage all of the various SE sites. As part of this effort, we are temporarily left with a design that is stupid, boring, and soul-less.

Comment: Understood, thanks Donald!